# Conda mini-forge environment unable to import cartopy package

Tags: conda, cartopy, mini-forge

I'm working on an M1 Mac system- I've created an environment on anaconda with miniforge and since I work with oceanographic data I need to install packages such as Xarray, Cartopy and Parcels. I used the Anaconda-Navigator package manager to install these packages on a separate environment (once with python 3.8 and once with 3.10). I then launched Anaconda Notebooks from the environment- however, on trying to import Cartopy and Parcels, I get the module not found error (note that Xarray does not have this issue)
this:
[A screenshot showing the following error on running the command 'import cartopy.crs as ccrs': ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITIWe.png)
Cartopy and Parcels both imported perfectly well when I was using Anaconda-Navigator (minus the latest update) **without** mini-forge, however, I really need mini-forge to overcome some issues with running Parcels
Here is what I've tried to get around this so far:
Reinstalling cartopy using the terminal
I'd really appreciate any help with this! I'm very new to all of this.